# Flash widget system

Tags: flash, system, widget

I want to create a little flash application, what would implement a widget system. Main points:

- Widgets are separate SWF files, loaded dynamically from a folder
- Active widgets and their position are saved on a given interval
- Widgets can be dragged after a long press (time of press can be set)
- Open source and free
- Not too important but maybe multi-page support? Something like on iPhone?

Is there any such widget system for Flash?

Comment: I haven't heard of any but could be a cool open-source project to start.